# uncaught reference error on button click when pass a foreach key

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

**When I pass the foreach key in function of my on click submit at last of code it gave me error uncaught reference error of given key, it is function response code and I want to edit the detail by its key but when I pass a key its gave me error of uncaught reference error**

i am request a transaction by key or then i append the html by given below and then i want to edit this transaction by its but when i pass the key it gave me error key are likes -M7BydBNVMYoV0LDJIR i don't know why it gave error after passing the key.

> 

```
<script>
    function detail_transaction(id) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "",
            data: {client_key: client_key, business_key: business, reference: reference},
            success: function (response) {
                document.getElementById("loader_image").style.display = "none";
                let name = response.data.name;
                let nowDate = new Date(response.data.created_at);
                let date = nowDate.toLocaleDateString();
                let res = '';
                let am = '';

                    res ='<div class="transaction-detail">\n' +
                        '<table class="table table-striped table-font">\n' +
                        '<thead>\n' +
                        '<tr>\n' +
                        '<th>Enteries</th>\n' +
                        '<th>You Gave</th>\n' +
                        '<th>You Get</th>\n' +
                        '<th>Balance</th>\n' +
                        '<th>Action</th>\n' +
                        '</tr>\n' +
                        '</thead>\n' +
                        '<tbody>\n';
                    let total_of_each = 0;

                    $.each(response.data.Transactions, function (key, data) {

                        res +=
                            '<tr>' +
                            '<td>' +
                            date +
                            '</td>';
                        if (data.amount > 0) {
                            res +=
                                '<td>' + 'Rs. ' + parseInt(data.amount).toLocaleString() + '</td>';
                            total_of_each = parseInt(total_of_each) - parseInt(data.amount);
                        } else {
                            res +=
                                '<td>' +
                                '</td>';
                            total_of_each = parseInt(total_of_each)
                        }
                        if (data.subamount > 0) {
                            total_of_each = parseInt(total_of_each) + parseInt(data.subamount);
                            res += '<td>' + 'Rs. ' + parseInt(data.subamount).toLocaleString() + '</td>';
                        } else {
                            res +=
                                '<td>' +
                                '</td>';
                            total_of_each = parseInt(total_of_each)
                        }

                        res +=
                            '<td>'
                            +'Rs. ' + parseInt(total_of_each).toLocaleString() +
                            '</td>' +

                            '<td><Button class="transaction-edit btn-font-size hiden" onclick="editTransaction(' + data.amount + ')" id="' + data.amount + '">Edit</Button>\n' +
                            ' <Button  onclick="deleteTransaction()" class="hiden transaction-delete btn-font-size mt-sm-0 mt-1 ">delete</Button></td>' +
                            '</tr>' +

                            '<div class="text-center customer-block" id="edit_transaction" style="display: none;">' +
                            '<div class="add-customer-main">' +
                            '<div class="clearfix">' +
                            '<span type="button" class="close p-1" onclick="edit_gave_close()">&times;</span>' +
                            '<h5 class="pt-4 pl-3"></h5>' +
                            '</div>' +
                            '<div class="add-customer-body text-left p-3">' +
                            '<label for="amount">Rs</label>' +

                            '<input type="text" required name="amount" id="edit_amount" class="form-control" onkeyup="negativeValue()">' +
                            '<p id="edit_amount_error" class="amount_error">invalid amount </p>'+

                            '<label for="detail">Detail (optional)</label>' +
                            '<textarea name="note" id="edit_note" class="form-control" cols="30" rows="2"></textarea>' +

                            '<label for="date">Date</label>' +
                            '<input type="date" name="date" id="edit_date" class="form-control">' +

                            '<input onclick="submit('+key+')" value="Update" class="btn btn-success mt-3 mb-3 float-right">' +
                            '</div>' +
                            '</div>' +
                            '</div>';
                    });

                }


                $('#main_table').html(res);
                $('#amount_block').html(am);
            }
        });
    }

</script>

<script>
    function submit(id){
       console.log(id)
       }
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please show the full code of `each` callback, and also the full text of the error.

Comment: ok i will show you

Comment: please see it now

Comment: Can you point the line the error occurs, and an example of really exact error message.

Comment: <input onclick="submit('+key+')">  this is error   business:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: M6j1iuc7WYAQCCoYly8 is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick (VM78 business:1)

Comment: OK, the error comes actually from HTML when you click the input. You've to wrap the key in quotes in `submit` argument, like so: `'<input onclick="submit(\''+key+'\')" ...`. Otherwise JS interprets the key as a variable name, and that variable is naturally not defined, that's why the error is triggered.

Comment: thanku so much Teemu